# .htaccess how can I virtual redirect m.website.com to website.com/mobile?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following structure:

- Root directory

  - index.php
  - [ mobile ]

    - index.php
    - [images]

What I want is that if people would visit http://m.website.com to still see that URL in their browser but it loads the files in the mobile directory. Is that possible?

(Or does anyone have a very good tutorial on .htaccess so I can learn how to do it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root directory of what I assume is the `m.website.com` subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if they came on mobile domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.website\.com$ [NC]
#rewrite request to Mobile folder
RewriteRule (.*) mobile/$1 [L]
```

Comment: add `RewriteCond $1 !^mobile/ [NC]` to prevent an infinite loop